# Techniques for placing text over a background image

Tags: css, background-image, overlay, positioning

Have a look at this website http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/ where the introductory text is placed over a background image. In this case - they use a table to display the text

`.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}`

Of course another way of achieving this would be to use absolute positioning but taking a mobile-first approach - I'm curious to know what would be the most lightweight solution (least amount of css) while keeping to best practices!

Comment: You should create a fiddle so we can fiddle around with your example :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the background: url styling that's the crux of it. You can use it on a DIV though. The rest of the styling is just about the div itself (text colour/div size).

Here's a minimalist example - this works fine on my Android phone:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    background: url(http://www.thewebbery.co.uk/Web04/SKP/Files/PITP1.jpg);
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:900;
    height:600;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image Here's some text over an image 
Some more over an image

</div>
</body>
</head>
```